# What is the most efficient to count trailing zeroes in an integer?

Tags: algorithm, math

normal way is

```
int main(){
  int a=2000,count=0,temp;
  while(a!=0)
  {
    temp=a%10;
    if(temp==0) count++
    else break;
    a/=10;
  }
  printf("%d",count);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: How about _defining_ efficient? Petr assumed the number of divisions should be minimized (and would seem to count modulus against that). Think about galloping search.

Comment: @greybeard, I just assumed division (and modulus), as it is usually the case, to be substantially slower than other arithmetics.

Comment: @Petr: perfectly fine. The OP shouldn't have the community guessing, though.

Comment: Note that many architectures have this built-in.  e.g. GNU C has `__builtin_ctz` which compiles efficiently.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Answer (score 6):

For a 32-bit integer (maximum value 2147483647) you only need a maximum of 4 tests. For 64 bits add one more with a test for 16 zeros.

Start with the larger powers of 10 and work down:

```
int countTrailingZeros(int n)
{
    int zeros = 0;
    if((n % 100000000) == 0)
    {
        zeros += 8;
        n /= 100000000;
    }
    if((n % 10000) == 0)
    {
        zeros += 4;
        n /= 10000;
    }
    if((n % 100) == 0)
    {
        zeros += 2;
        n /= 100;
    }
    if((n % 10) == 0)
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    return zeros;
}
```

This has a better worst-case performance, but if 9/10ths of the numbers you pass it have no trailing zeros then the average case is worse. It just depends on what values you are passing to it in the typical case.

However, if 9/10ths of the numbers you pass it have no trailing zeros then you probably shouldn't worry about optimizing your original code in the first place since it will break in the first iteration of your loop 90% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can adapt the idea of Binary search here.
May be it's difficult to code but it's an idea (as you have asked for most efficient way, I am just presenting this idea).

I am not just talking about 32-bit integer or 64 bit integer.

This works very well when the number of 0's are high otherwise also it should be efficient.

Say your number is `n`.

First check if `n%(10^1) == 0` if yes

then check for  `n%(10^2) == 0` if yes

then check for  `n%(10^4) == 0` if yes the `10^8 ....10^16`. I think you got the idea.

So finally you will get a point where `n % 10^(2x) !=0`, and now you know that no. of `0`'s are between `x` and `2x`.

So again do a binary search starting with `x`, `x+1` ,`x+2` ....till you don't find the case where `n % 10^(2y) != 0 (x < y <= 2x)`. Repeat the same process.

The time complexity would be (if you have K `0`'s) :

Best case will be :

```
    O(logK)
```

Worst case will be:

```
     ceil(log(K)) + ceil(log(k/2)) + ..... 1 = ~ O(logK)
```

Comment: When estimating time complexity for big integers, you should always remember that any arithmetic operations on them will not be `O(1)`, so the complexity here will not be so good.

Comment: @Petr You are right, but when I said big integers I dint mean BigInteger in Java but I was talking about `long long` in C++(GCC) and `long integer` in python. However I edited that part.

Comment: There it gallops… On the complexity of BigNum-Ops: the way I remember the RAM model, the machine has as many digits as needed "for the input values", times a constant (not input-dependant) factor. Here, the biggest number needed is about twice as long as the only input: O(1).

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean by gallops?

Answer (score 2):

At least you speed this up by having only one divison per zero:

```
c = 1;
while (a % c == 0) {
    c *= 10;
    cout ++;
}
```

(probably you will also have to accurately process case when `*=10` overflows).

This is still the same complexity. However, for `int`s I doubt that you need any better complexity, as the maximal possible number of zeros is very small.